# Correct Value(s) to store in TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD

Tags: android, gps, exif

Thanks for reading this question. I am sure the experts on this site will be able to provide the help I need.

I am trying to write an app which allows users to edit the exif information of the photos on their Android Phone.

As a part of improved user experience, I want to apply data validation where ever possible.

For the Exif Tag - TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD I am not able to apply the validation correctly.

Here is the part of code that I have applied :

```
String strGPSProc = etGPSProc.getText().toString();

if(strGPSProc.equalsIgnoreCase("GPS") || strGPSProc.equalsIgnoreCase("CELLID") || strGPSProc.equalsIgnoreCase("WLAN") || strGPSProc.equalsIgnoreCase("MANUAL") ) {
        returnValue = true;
}else {
        returnValue=false;
        showToast("Incorrect value for GPS Processing Method. Correct value options are GPS, CELLID, WLAN or MANUAL.");
        etGPSProc.requestFocus();
}
```

This code checks if the value entered in the EditText meant for GPSProcessingMethod, has any one of the four prescribed value as described in the documentation of EXIF.

But when I try to save this using setAttribute() and saveAttributes() functions, a non catch-able exception appears in logcat.

```
Unsupported encoding for GPSProcessingMethod
```

I understand from Exif Documentation that values for GPSProcessingMethod needs to be stored with some header information.

I need some expert advise on how to implement this correctly, with out using any other 3rd part classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoridng to the [Exif specification](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF):

> **GPSProcessingMethod**
>
> A character string recording the name of the method used for location finding. The first byte indicates the character
> code used (Table 6､Table 7), and this is followed by the name of the method. Since the Type is not ASCII, NULL
> termination is not necessary

Atually, Table 6 lists the character codes as 8 byte sequences, so the above should probably  read "The first **bytes** indicate...". Anyway, the character code designation for ASCII is defined as `41.H, 53.H, 43.H, 49.H, 49.H, 00.H, 00.H, 00.H.`, Unicode is (unsurprisingly) `55.H, 4E.H, 49.H, 43.H, 4F.H, 44.H, 45.H, 00.H`. I guess these should be all you need.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Just discovered that `ExifInterface.setAttribute()` only supports String values... You could try encoding the value at the beginning of your string, but I doubt that would work. Sounds like the encoding should be handled by the `setAttribute()` or `saveAttributes()` method. Could it be a bug in the API? I had a look at the source code, but the actual writing of values is done by native code so I stopped digging further.

Comment: Thanks mate. This means that I should rather make this field read only instead of allowing users to edit it. At-least till the bug is corrected.